# Check data in array for null values

Tags: php, arrays

I want to check data in array to see if there are null values. If there are, I'd like to display an alert.

*Example:*

```
$data = array(1 => 'AKB48', 2 => '', 3 => 'JKT48');
```

The Array of index 1 `($data[1])` is null, and I want it to display `"WARNING, data in array is null"`

if data in array does not have empty/null values then don't show an alert:

```
$data = array(1 => 'AKB48', 2 => 'HKT48', 3 => 'JKT48');
```

*(the above array will no trigger an alert)*

How can I achieve this solution?

Comment: Do you want to display a warning or suppress the warning?

Comment: @user1798945 i want you to differentiate between `null` and `empty`

Answer (score 0):

something like this?

```
$data = array(1 => 'AKB48', 2 => '', 3 => 'JKT48');

foreach($data as $val) {
    if($val == '') {
        echo "alert, array consist of empty value";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$data = array(1 => 'AKB48', 2 => '', 3 => 'JKT48');

foreach($data as $v)
{
  if(empty($v))
  {
    echo "Array contains null value";
    break;
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Something like this?

`isDefined` will check if the value is a valid non-empty String.

```
function isDefined($var) {
  return isset($var) && !is_null($var) && !empty($var);
}

$data = array(
  array('AKB48', 'HKT48', NULL),
  array('AKB49', '',      'JKT49'),
  array('AKB50', 'HKT50', 'JKT50')
);

for ($i = 0; $i < count($data); $i++) {
  foreach ($data[$i] as $col) {
    if (!isDefined($col)) {
      echo "<<<Attention: Array #$i contains an empty value!>>> ";
    }
  }
}
```

[Running example of code above.](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/49ecab28627a2365b9aa57d16fae048d6d6430a6)

Comment: I used a for loop to display which row had null data. Did not want to create a separate variable to increment with...